# Provider is not wrapping the login and signup pages in NextJS 13 and NextUI

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13, nextui

I'm trying to create a signup and login page using NextJS 13 and NextUI. The dark mode theme setting is applied to the HomePage but not to the login and signup pages. Also, I'm trying to fetch the signIn function from a custom useAuth() hook, but the function is not being called when the submit button is pressed. I guess the login and signup pages are not wrapped under the provider.

**Here is the folder structure:**

[image: 1]

**This is the folder structure of Auth pages**

[image: 2]

**This is page.js file:**

```
"use client";

import { createTheme } from "@nextui-org/react";
import Head from "next/head";
import { AuthProvider } from "./hooks/useAuth";
import GlobalNavbar from "./pages/components/GlobalNavbar";
import App from "./App";

export default function Page() {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <GlobalNavbar />
      <App />
    </AuthProvider>
  );
}
```

**This is App.js file:**

*PS: Removed the import statements for showcase purposes*

```
function App() {
  return (
    <NextThemesProvider
      defaultTheme="dark"
      attribute="class"
      value={{
        light: lightTheme.className,
        dark: darkTheme.className,
      }}
    >
      <NextUIProvider>
        <Navigation />
      </NextUIProvider>
    </NextThemesProvider>
  );
}
```

Inside the Navigation component, I just navigate it to the HomePage component. So when, the homepage loads, it loads in dark mode, and I was also able to access the values in the AuthProvider. But if I change the url to ↓

> http://localhost:3000/auth/login

The theme is in light and I was also not able to access the values from the AuthProvider

I tried migrating the login and signup pages into the pages folder but it still didn't work.